# WPF Nested Data Grid with fixed header and sub header

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I want to create a WPF nested data grid which will have a fixed header and sub header. Below are some points which are required to create the nested grid control:-

1. The Main grid rows will have data aligned to the Main header columns and the nested grid rows will have data aligned to the sub-header columns.
2. On click of Main grid row, the nested grid rows should get displayed with data corresponding to sub header columns.
3. User must be able to expand multiple Main grid rows.

Below is an image which depicts the grid which we require.

[image]

As shown in the above grid, the grey rows are the main rows aligned to the Main header and the two white rows are the sub rows aligned to the Sub header(operacao, autent., hora etc.)

The collection(Main grid) which has to be bound to this control has another collection as property which contains the rows of the Sub rows(Nested grid).

Answer (score 1):

This functionality can be achieved by using following hierarchy:

1. In order to create such a control you will have to create labels
   separate from the grid with the expected design and align their
   width to the collection properties which are meant to be grid
   columns.
2. Create a Custom control inherited by a Data-grid and handle the
   Mouse and Key events in it for the Data-grid.
3. Use this custom control in the Main XAML file with Data Source equal
   to the Main Collection(List) and bind the columns of the grid to the
   properties of the data source.
4. Use a Data-Template inside the Data-grid with a RowDetailsTemplate
   which will further contain the custom control(Data-grid).
5. Bind the inner collection present in the Main collection to this
   inner custom control. This is how nesting can be achieved by using
   Data-grid components.
6. For the expand and collapse functionality override the Mouse
   Down/Mouse Up event of the custom control and handle the Row Details
   visibility of the control. This is how you can control the expansion
   and collapse of the grid rows.

You can also override the click events and handle the further navigation. Also, in order to achieve the same design do some adjustments in the grid columns. You can achieve this behavior by the mentioned approach.